# Angular 2 redirect url when going back to the page

Tags: angular, routes

I have an Angular 2 page that has this type of routing model:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', pathMatch: 'prefix', redirectTo: 'announcement' },
   { path: 'announcement', component: AnnouncementComponent },
   { path: 'important-documents', component: ImportantDocumentsComponent },
   { path: 'reservations-and-orders', component: ReservationsAndOrdersComponent},
   { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
   { path: '**', redirectTo: 'announcement'}
 ];
```

When I open a pdf-file in my ImportantDocumentsComponent and after that try to get back to the previous page by pressing the back-button in the browser a problem occurres. The page informs me that requested url was not found in this server. I assume that this happens because in reality the angular page has only one url, and the browser is trying to load the page url + path. I thought I could go around it with this:

```
 { path: '**', redirectTo: 'announcement'}
```

but it didn't seem to do the trick.

I would like to know that how can I prevent this type of url error from happening, so that the browser would redirect to the correct url when going back.

Thanks already beforehand.

Comment: If just redirect needed for invalid path, try like this - `{ path: '**', component: AnnouncementComponent }` Just put as the last path as you show in your snippet

Comment: Didn't work. It just broke the routing module and rerouted all the paths to AnnouncementComponent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Location Service and "Back" function should do the work. Location Service should be imported from "angular2/router" in older versions of Angular 2. For newer "@angular/common". Below is case when you have back button in your form.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({ directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] })
@RouteConfig([
    {...},
])
class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _location: Location) {
    }
    backClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}
```

In case for back button clicked on webbrowser use [PlatformLocation](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation) and then you can define **onPopState**.

```
this.location.onPopState(()=>{
  this.location.back();
});
```